# How to use in html body a variable that's been defined in script in the head part

Tags: javascript, html

In the following code how can I correctly insert the val `testName` defined in the function `initialize()` in the field `Name` in the body?

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function intialize()
{
    var testName="John";
}
</script>
</head>

<body onload="intialize()">
<input id="Name" type="textbox" value=testName>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use document ready :

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){
      $('#Name').val('testName');
});

</script>
</head>

<body>
<input id="Name" type="textbox" value=""/>
</body>
</html>
```

Used the id, Name, and set the value to 'testName' once the document is ready.

Answer (score 4):

Well, if you're using jQuery, you could just include this in the function:

```
$("#Name").val(testval);
```

You might have to put the script in $(document).ready() though.

Comment: With jQuery you'd normally use `$(document).ready()` rather than using the `onload` event, however putting your suggested jQuery code directly in the OP's `initialise()` function (which is called `onload`) should work too.

Answer (score 3):

This. It's easy, and you don't have to worry about any of this jquery mess.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function intialize()
{
    var testName="John";
    document.getElementById("Name").value = testname;
}
</script>
</head>

<body onload="intialize()">
<input id="Name" type="textbox">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try declaring it outside the function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var testName;
function intialize()
{
    testName="John";
}
</script>
```

But it will become a global variable.

Comment: I am not that familiar with Jquery.Hope this normal JS solution might help.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which is how can the value in that variable be applied to the input field within the HTML? Moving the variable declaration doesn't help at all.

Answer (score 1):

You have jQuery available so USE it. Don't use an older version than [1.6.1](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.1.min.js) though..

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var testName="John";
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#Name').val(testName);
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<input id="Name" type="text">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why not use a version older than 1.6.1? Is there a way to automatically use the newest available version without getting in the code every once in a while to update the version? Your suggestion is working without the document ready use so can I skip it or is it a must?